# c++ functions. using loops

Tags: c++

I just started learning functions and I am struggling to solve this. Lecturer gave a hint that you have to start calculating from the bottom aka 256 to the top.

This is the formula:

[image: Formula from lecturer]

This is the code I have so far (it's incorrect obviously):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int funkc(int x);

int main() {
  double ats;
  int x;

  cout << "enter x value" << endl;
  cin >> x;
  ats = funkc(x);
  cout << ats << endl;
}

int funkc(int x){
  int n;
  int o;
  int a;
  n=256;

  while(n >= 2){
    n = n/2;
    o = x*x + (n/(x*x));
    a = x*x + (n/o);
    o = a;
  }
  return a;
}
```

EDIT:this is what i came up with. When input is 5 answer should be 0,0398732 but this outputs 0,0399363. I can't figure out why

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
double o;
double a;

double Y(double x);

int main() {

   double x;

 cout << "enter x value" << endl;
 cin >> x;

   cout << Y(x)<<endl;
}

double Y(double x){


   for(int n=256; n>1; n/=2){
      o=x*x+(n/(x*x));
       a=x*x+((n/2)/o);
       o=a;
   }


   return 1/o;
}
```

Comment: A first problem : you should declare `x` as `double`. Here you are performing integer division and thus truncation appears

Comment: And welcome to SO. I should have began with that. Sorry

Comment: Another issue: you are missing the "256" term !

Comment: I think you need to initialise `double denominator = x*x;`, then loop through `n = [256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]`, for each `n` value, calculate: `denominator = x*x + (n / denominator)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a recursive function, meaning that the function essentially calls itself.

This function can be expressed as:

```
r = x2 + (n / d)
```

d is a divisor, in the first instance, it is x2. In subsequent calls, it is the result from the previous step. Even though the problem itself is recursive, it's simple enough to do in an iterative loop instead:

```
double findY(double x) 
{
    // let's pre-compute x*x since we reuse it a lot
    double x2 = x * x;

    // first step, the divisor is x2, so we will set that as initial value
    double divisor = x2;

    // we can use a for loop since we are looping from 256 to 1, but use divide instead of ++n
    for (int n = 256; n > 1; n /= 2)
    {
        // our recursive function as explained above
        // the answer is assigned to divisor and used in the next loop
        divisor = x2 + (n / divisor);
    }

    // EDIT: forgot that we need 1/answer to get the final result
    return 1.0/divisor;
}
```

EDIT: Also as stated in the comments from other users, you have initialised X as int when it should be a double, so that the divisions don't return an int.

You have ats as a double, so you were on the right track, but it is getting an int returned from your function.

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested but now it just returns zeros.

Comment: @lama did you make sure you are using double as your data type for x?

Comment: Also just noticed i used a float for the divide in the end instead of a double for 1.0, i'll edit it - EDIT: also i had the divider as an int, I've changed that to double now.

Comment: You can incorporate `1 / divisor` into the loop: `double y = 0; for (int n = 256; n > 0; n /= 2) y = n / (x2 + y); return y;`.